How to convert a changing text file to json with correct formatting. Data will displayed as a HTML
I have a PowerShell script that prints out the following information as a text file.
I converted that text file as a json file which I Can index however, the goal is to convert this data into a HTML File and the output of the data changes.
For example, I have 2 vm's for now. However, I could have 5 in the future.
I'm used to dealing with Json file that look like this and not the one I've created.
The json file that I have to work with
[
  "Information from Resource Group",
  "",
  "Virtual Machines",
  "ffx-filesvr-001",
  "ffx-sql-001",
  "",
  "Data Disk",
  "ddisk-01",
  "ddisk-02",
  "ffx-filesvr-001_OsDisk_1_0fdb129b4fec4ea3b70cfb9310544730",
  "ffx-sql-001_disk2_7cee250c32ab4cfe8ddf5aeaf587ae3f",
  "ffx-sql-001_disk3_4169e3002c074d4db44608ce9a41cbe3",
  "ffx-sql-001_OsDisk_1_d5b3929fe8864475b9aa46fdb2a869f4",
  "",
  "Network Interfaces",
  "ffx-filesvr-001-nic-6rc4m5ed335gc",
  "ffx-sql-001-nic-6rc4m5ed335gc",
  "",
  "Current Image ID used",
  "/subscriptions/47ab8099-6a64-4074-a3b8-b3a4fab2f798/resourceGroups/dev-dp-imagegallery/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/dev_dp_imagegallery/images/Server2019",
  "",
  "Disk Encryption Status",
  "",
  "ffx-filesvr-001",
  "",
  "OsVolumeEncrypted          : NotEncrypted",
  "DataVolumesEncrypted       : NotEncrypted",
  "OsVolumeEncryptionSettings : ",
  "ProgressMessage            : No Encryption extension or metadata found on the VM",
  "",
  "ffx-sql-001",
  "",
  "OsVolumeEncrypted          : NotEncrypted",
  "DataVolumesEncrypted       : NotEncrypted",
  "OsVolumeEncryptionSettings : ",
  "ProgressMessage            : No Encryption extension or metadata found on the VM",
  "",
  "Disk Encryption Set",
  "There's no disk encryption set in this resource group"
]



.... and what should the resulting HTML look like?

data conversion requires 2 thoughts: syntax rules and a glossary, for each part. I supose you already know them for JSON but what are they for your converted Powershel data? and did they really respect any syntax? I doubt!

also: you didn't really made that text a viable JSON.

Pretty easy HTML Format
The Titles will be H1 tags and the information below will be  tags
Virtual machine : h1
VM1 and VM2 would be 
